# Using findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths to change datasource for CAD files- ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, cad

I try to use "findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths" in order to change datasource for CAD files. This code works fine but when there no cad layers to work with, despite this the code will print 'findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths'. How can i get this print message only when the code will find cad layer?

```
import arcpy,os,sys,string
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"G:\PROJECTS\daras\gis"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print mxdname # print list of mxd's in the folder
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"G:\PROJECTS\daras\gis\\" + mxdname)
    mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths(r"E:\daras\gis\layers", r"G:\PROJECTS\daras\gis\layers")
    print 'findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths'
    mxd.save()
del mxd
```

this is the result:

> > > ```
> > > airplane noise2 a3.mxd
> > > findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
> > > environment.mxd
> > > findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
> > > environment011.mxd
> > > findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
> > > environment012.mxd
> > > findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
> > > ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to loop through the layers inside each MXD to check the layer sources.

this should look similar to this

```
import arcpy,os,sys,string
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"G:\PROJECTS\daras\gis"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print mxdname # print list of mxd's in the folder
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"G:\PROJECTS\daras\gis\\" + mxdname)
    cad = False
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
        if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
             if lyr.dataSource.find(".dwg") != -1:
                 cad = True
                 break
    if cad:
        mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths(r"E:\daras\gis\layers", r"G:\PROJECTS\daras\gis\layers")
        print 'findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths'
        mxd.save()
    del mxd
```

Since you cannot check for the data type directly (the path to the source file is broken) you have to check if the data source as a DWG file extension

Comment: i get  IOError: "G:\PROJECTS\daras\gis\layers\3_2_16\blue-line.dwg\Polyline" does not exist

Comment: Yeah, right. The path is broken and we cannot determine the dataType because the file doesn't exist at the given location.
I corrected the code above to take this into account